# Querying jsonb that contains arrays and booleans

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a jsonb field. The content looks like this:

```
select myfield from mytable

{"1": [1, 2, 3], "2": [1, 2], "3": [1, 2], "4": true}
{}
{"1": [6, 11]}
{"3": [2], "4": true}
```

So far I've managed to run queries like:

```
-- Select all rows that, for key "1", are null
select addl from live_feeds where (addl->>'1') is null
```

```
-- Select all rows that, for key "4", are true
select addl from live_feeds where (addl->>'4')::boolean is true;
```

But after trying a few different approaches, I couldn't get this one to work:

```
Select all rows that, for key "1", include value 1
```

What kind of casting/operator should I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this ([function json doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html))

> `@>`: Does the left JSON value contain within it the right value?

```
select addl from live_feeds where (addl->>'1')::jsonb @> '[1]'
```